# Complex semi-algebraic sets

Tags: reference-request, semialgebraic-geometry

**Definition.** A subset $S$ of $\mathbb{R}^n$ is called *semi-algebraic* if $S$ is a finite Boolean combination of sets of the form $\{ x \in \mathbb{R}^n \mid p(x) \ge 0\}$, where $p \in \mathbb{R}[x]$.

View $\mathbb{C}^n$ as a real $2n$-dimensional vector space and let $\mathsf{T}: \mathbb{C}^n \longrightarrow \mathbb{R}^{2n}$ be the bijective linear transformation such that
$$
z \in \mathbb{C}^n \stackrel{\mathsf{T}}{\longmapsto} 
\begin{bmatrix}
\Re z_1 \\
\Im z_1 \\
\vdots \\
\Re z_n \\
\Im z_n
\end{bmatrix} \in \mathbb{R}^{2n}.
$$

As suggested in a [comment here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2313782/analogue-of-semialgebraic-sets-over-complex-numbers#comment4761233_2313782), call $S \subseteq \mathbb{C}^n$ *complex semi-algebraic* or *semi-algebraic in $\mathbb{C}^n$* if $\mathsf{T}(S)$ is semi-algebraic in $\mathbb{R}^{2n}$.

**Question.** Is there an equivalent definition that involves, perhaps, a set of inequalities involving the modulus?

As an example, if $S := \{z \in \mathbb{C} \mid 1 - \vert z^2 \vert \ge 0\}$, then $\mathsf{T}(S) = \{ x \in \mathbb{R}^2 \mid 1 - (x^2 + y^2) \ge 0 \}$ is semi-algebraic in $\mathbb{R}^2$.

**Edit:** I've decided to add some context given that someone decided to downvote this post.

The *nonnegative inverse eigenvalue problem* (NIEP) is to characterize the spectra of (entrywise) nonnegative matrices. The NIEP is unsolved for matrices of order greater than four.

Let $x \in \mathbb{C}^n$. Say $x$ is *realizable* if the multiset $\Lambda(x) := \{x_1,\dots,x_n\}$ is the spectrum of a nonnegative matrix of order $n$. Let $\mathbb{L}^n := \{ x \in \mathbb{C}^n \mid \Lambda(x) = \sigma(A),~A \in \mathsf{M}_n(\mathbb{R}),~A \ge 0 \}$. (There are some well-known necessary conditions on this set, but we do not mention them here.)

In reviewing the NIEP, Bharali and Holtz [[MR2399570](https://epubs.siam.org/doi/abs/10.1137/050645075)] state

> Finally, it follows from the Tarski–Seidenberg theorem [38, 29] that all realizable $n$-tuples form a *semialgebraic set* (see also [16]); i.e., for any given $n$, **there exist only finitely many polynomial inequalities that are necessary and sufficient for an $n$-tuple $\Lambda$ to be realizable** [emphasis added] as the spectrum of some nonnegative matrix $A$ (this observation was communicated to us by Friedland).

As illustrated above, this is clearly not the case and demonstrates the need for defining a *complex semi-algebraic* set beyond what I proffered above. Furthermore, a rigorous, "local" definition would give us a certificate of what it means to *solve* the NIEP.

Comment: Could you be more precise (than "involving the modulus") on what you allow and what you don't allow to define subsets?

Comment: @YCor: I make no requirements on the inequalities; I mentioned modulus because inequalities involving complex numbers are not possible without it.

Comment: Then $\mathbb{R}\subset\mathbb{C}$ would be a "*complex* semi-algebraic" subset according to your definition, and also of course a real algebraic subset of odd dimension. Are you ok with allowing this?

Comment: Also, you obtain all the (real) semi-algebraic subsets of $\mathbb{R}^{2n}$ in this way. So you're asking if every real semi-algebraic subset of $\mathbb{R}^{2n}$ can be expressed in some way in terms of the norm on $\mathbb{C}^n$, correct?

Comment: By the way (and sorry for the many questions), would it be interesting to define a notion of complex semi-algebraic set by some $|p_i(z)|\geq c$ for complex $p_i$ and real $c$, instead?

Comment: @Qfwfq: pertaining to your first comment, the set of real numbers is *not* a subset of the set of complex numbers. 

One may "view" $\mathbb{R}$ as a subset of $\mathbb{C}$ given that the mapping $x \in \mathbb{R} \longmapsto x+0i$ is a field isomorphism. 

Thus, it is more accurate to say that, under the definition above, the real-axis in the complex plane is complex algebraic since the x-axis is semi-algebraic in $\mathbb{R}^2$.

Thus, it is inaccurate to conclude that "$\mathbb{R}$ is complex algebraic" because it is not a subset of $\mathbb{C}$.

Comment: @Qfwfq: pertaining to your third comment, I would accept that definition so long as it agrees with the definition above, but this seems difficult to prove.

Comment: That's not the usual definition of semialgebraic set. Usually they are taken to be a finite union of sets $P_i$ which are each defined by one *or more* polynomial equalities and inequalities. Are you restricting to semialgebraic sets of a special form?

Comment: @ZachTeitler: no, this was an oversight on my part. I have edited the post to reflect your comment.

Comment: Are you allowing equations, e.g. $|z|-z=0$, too? Anyway, I have trouble trying to describe the positive ortant in $\mathbb{C}$ using the norm.

Comment: Are you asking if every complex semialgebraic set is the preimage of a real semialgebraic set via the map $z\mapsto(|z_1|,\dots,|z_n|)$?

Comment: @BenMcKay: your question pre-supposes the concept of a complex semi-algebraic set – has such a notion been defined already?

Comment: @DimaPasechnik: I am not forbidding anything; I simply want to know, with the definition above, how one can define a complex semi-algebraic set without appealing to the mapping above.

Comment: @PietroPaparella: I don't know if such a notion has been defined before; I was using the term "complex semi-algebraic set" as you defined it in your question.

Comment: Do you disagree with what [MR2399570] says in the place you quoted in boldface? I suppose they mean the usual identification of $\mathbb{C}$ as $\mathbb{R}\oplus \sqrt{-1}\mathbb{R}$, and everything works as claimed.

Comment: @DimaPasechnik: it may be possible that their conclusion is correct, but their argument that leads to the conclusion is not. It is clear that there must be polynomial inequalities in $\Re x_1, \Im x_1,\dots,\Re x_n, \Im x_n$, but what is desired are equations and/or inequalities in $x_1, \dots, x_n$.

Comment: What's wrong with inequalities in $\Re x_k, \Im x_k$ ? They do describe the $x_k$'s. And showing that the solutions to NIEP form a semialgebraic set is easy, one needs to recall that a projection of a semialgebraic set is semialgebraic.

Comment: @DimaPasechnik: your comment hints at points to the crux of my question: what do polynomial inequalities in $\Re x_k$, $\Im x_k$ ($1 \le k \le n$) imply about the complex variables $x_1,\dots,x_n$?

Comment: One further point regarding NIEP is that there the complex semialgebraic set in question is invariant under conjugation.

Comment: @DimaPasechnik: yes. I work on the NIEP and am one of the world’s experts on the problem. Hence my original post.

Comment: you never explained what in your opinion is wrong with MR2399570. It is certainly true that $\mathbb{L}^n=\mathbf{T}^{-1}(S)$ for $S$ a semialgebraic set.

Comment: @DimaPasechnik: 1) as quoted above, Bharali ad Holtz asset that $\mathbb{L}^n$ is “semi-algebraic” in the real sense; 2) they never defined *complex semi-algebraic set* in the manner in which I did above; 3) the conclusion about polynomial inequalities is, given the example I gave above, at the very least problematic; 4) their proof sketch implies my definition and therefore the problems in the three items above abound.

Comment: please see my answer regarding MR2399570 below. Hope it clarifies.

Comment: There are still some loose threads which have not been entirely sewn up. Following up on YCor's question on definability constraints: the collection of semi-algebraic sets can also be defined so that by definition it is closed under taking images along projection maps (and then Tarski-Seidenberg assures us we could do with less). Should I assume you don't allow that, i.e., "definability" here excludes existential quantification? Also, would you allow the modulus map to be seen as a function $\mathbb{C} \to \mathbb{C}$, i.e., as the interpretation of an unary function symbol in the signature?

Comment: @ToddTrimble: I’m sure those are great questions you’re asking, but, alas, I don’t have the background in semi-algebraic geometry/logic to answer them.

Answer (score 1):

Here I unroll the argument in [MR2399570] showing that $\mathbb{L}^n=\mathbf{T}^{-1}(S)$ for a semialgebraic set $S$, to show that at worst [loc.cit.] is a bit too brief, but no more that that.

Given an entrywise nonnegative $n\times n$ matrix $A$, its $n$-tuple of
eigenvalues is specified by the polynomial identity
$$ \det(\lambda I -A)=\prod_k (\lambda -\lambda_k).\tag{1}$$
On the other hand
$$ \det(\lambda I -A)=\sum_{k=0}^n a_k(A)\lambda^k,
\qquad \prod_k (\lambda -\lambda_k)=\sum_{k=0}^n \sigma_k(\Lambda)\lambda^k,$$
where $a_k$ are polynomials in the entries of $A$, and $\sigma_k$ are (symmetric) polynomials in $\lambda_j$'s. Thus we can eliminate $\lambda$ from (1), so that it becomes
$$ a_k(A)=\sigma_k(\Lambda),\qquad 0\leq k\leq n.\tag{2}$$
Writing $\lambda_k=\mu_k+\sqrt{-1}\nu_k$, $\mu=(\mu_1,\dots,\mu_n)$, $\nu=(\nu_1,\dots,\nu_n)$,
$\sigma_k(\Lambda)=\alpha(\mu,\nu)+\sqrt{-1}\beta(\mu,\nu)$ for real polynomials $\alpha$, $\beta$, and noting that $a_k(A)$ are real, one re-writes (2) as
$$ a_k(A)=\alpha_k(\mu,\nu), \quad 0=\beta_k(\mu,\nu)\qquad 0\leq k\leq n.\tag{3}$$

Thus, $\Lambda\in\mathbb{L}^n$ iff there exists $A\geq 0$ so that (3) holds.
We now have a semialgebraic set
$$(\exists A)\ [(A\geq 0)\wedge (a_k(A)=\alpha_k(\mu,\nu), \  0=\beta_k(\mu,\nu)\quad 0\leq k\leq n)],\tag{4}$$
which describes $\mathbb{L}^n$, and from which by Tarski-Seidenberg $A$ may be eliminated, to obtain $S$, a semialgebraic set with variables $\mu$ and $\nu$ only, as claimed.

---

*Edit*: most known necessary conditions for $\Lambda\in\mathbb{L}^n$ are naturally viewed in terms of $\mu$ and $\nu$, e.g. nonegativity of $k$-power sums $s_k(\Lambda)=\sum_j \lambda_j^k$ (which is (3) in arxiv.org/pdf/1712.05454.pdf).

Appearence of symmetric polynomials $s_k$ is not a coincidence; indeed the set $S$ admits the action of the symmetric group $S_n$ permuting $\lambda_j$'s, as well as the complex conjugation involution. It would be interesting to know whether it's always possible to use only the polynomials invariant under this group to define $S$.

On the other hand, one might want to break the $S_n$-symmetry by adding the condition $\mu_1\geq \mu_2\geq ...\mu_n$ to (4); as well (4) allows to impose further geometric conditions on $\Lambda$, e.g. it's elements forming a convex $n$-gon, matrix [*semi-stability*](https://core.ac.uk/download/pdf/82090358.pdf) (all $\mu_j\leq 0$), etc.

Comment: What was claimed is that the set is semi-algebraic in the *complex variables* (which is non-sensical) not the real variables. Again, I **fully** understand that it is semi-algebraic in the real variables but you continue to not understand my objection.

Comment: They never say in [MR2399570] explicitly what variables they use. While your question on whether $|\cdot |$ would suffice to produce   the needed inequalites is fine, there is nothing  wrong with [MR2399570].

Comment: I respectfully disagree. Their treatment of that topic is slipshod (although somewhat acceptable because they were trying to summarize). The inequalities that are required for the solution of the NIEP are in terms of the complex variables, not the real and imaginary variables, which is why my question is pertinent.

Comment: @PietroPaparella in your comment to your question you said "it may be possible that their conclusion is correct, but their argument that leads to the conclusion is not. ". I have trouble matching "I fully understand" with "it may be possible that...", which clearly says you had doubts about their argument. I am glad my answer helped to clarify this.

Comment: I don't understand why you don't consider this appoach a solution to NIEP. For a fixed $n$, it's a question of running a finite exact algorithm on the system (4) of polynomial equations and inequalities with integer coefficients to obtain  $S$, and thus a description of the $\mathbb{L}^n$.

Comment: let me try this one more time: what do the polynomial inequalities in $\Re x_k, \Im x_k$, $1 \le k \le n$, say about the the complex variables $x_1,\dots,x_n$? I can tell you from my experience working on the NIEP that the latter is preferred over the former.

Comment: NIEP is, formally, "given $\Lambda$, is there $A\geq 0$ such that...". From this angle, semialgebraic approach gives you an answer. Again, it's perfectly meaningful to ask your question about $|\cdot |$, I do not object to this.

Comment: I do not disagree here, but the known necessary conditions are given in term of the list of numbers (real or complex) which is more elegant than having to consider the real and imaginary parts (see, e.g., https://arxiv.org/pdf/1712.05454.pdf).

Comment: I added a discussion of this to the answer. There are conditions on matrices most naturally described in terms of real and imaginary parts, e.g. matrix stability.

Answer (score 1):

I will jot down some stray (and easy) thoughts, in an effort to engage the question and see whether some aspects of it can be made more precise.

Going out on a limb, I suppose a baseline assumption is that we start out with a collection of basic sets in $\mathbb{C}^n$ (letting $n$ vary) that are considered "definable", such as graphs of complex polynomial functions in several variables, and inverse images of closed and open intervals of $\mathbb{R}$ (including rays) with respect to the modulus function $\mathbb{C} \to \mathbb{R}$. A key question is what sorts of operations we allow to "close up" this collection, but again, I think from the form of the question that minimally we want to close up under the Boolean operations of finite intersections, finite unions, and complementation. Probably also cartesian products of definable sets should be considered definable. Whether we want to close up under taking direct images along projection maps is not yet known, but that would be a powerful assumption and would probably trivialize the problem. On the other hand, if taking direct images is *not* allowed as a basic operation, then we have more work to do to make the problem precise.

For example, although it wouldn't follow directly from the minimalistic assumptions above, I would guess the OP would allow the set $\{z \in \mathbb{C}: |z + i| - |z - i| \leq 0\}$ as one of the stockpile of definable sets. Similarly for $\{z \in \mathbb{C}: |z + i| - |z - i| \geq 0\}$, and so then the intersection, which is the real axis, would be allowed in the stockpile. Similarly the imaginary axis would be allowed.

Let's see if we can get projection maps to the real and imaginary axes (and by that point, we would be pretty close to the realm of ordinary semialgebraic sets in $\mathbb{R}^{2n}$, although certain issues of definablity would still need to be sorted out). I suspect that the function $z \mapsto \frac1{2}(|1 + z|^2 - |z|^2 - 1)$ would be considered by OP to be a definable function of the form $\mathbb{C} \to \mathbb{R}$; this of course is $z \mapsto Re(z)$. We aren't quite done, but if we now consider the relation

$$\{(z, t) \in \mathbb{C}^2: Re(z) = Re(t) \wedge |t + i| = |t - i|\}$$

(where $=$ in $\mathbb{R}$ is $\leq \wedge \geq$), then this is the graph of a function $\mathbb{C} \to \mathbb{C}$ that represents projection onto the real axis, and projection onto the imaginary axis is obtained similarly.

I am making this CW as it is not clear whether response this would be considered satisfactory to the OP. But I would like the OP to engage seriously with the whole issue of definability (roughly, which functions, baseline sets, and set-forming operations do we allow) that is at the crux of the question once you dig in. Also, to head off one possibility at the pass (and speaking more in a moderator capacity): neither Dima nor I nor any one of the community members seeking to engage have meant to be "patronizing" in any way toward the OP. Some of the discussion in comments I have found unfortunate (and have had to edit, as a moderator); I hope the tone of this response suggests that some patience and care is needed to resolve the issues that are basic here.

Comment: Nice! Also $Re(z) = \frac{1}{4}(|z+1|^2-|z-1|^2)$, and $Im(z) = Re(-iz) = \frac{1}{4}(|-iz+1|^2-|-iz-1|^2) = \frac{1}{4}(|z+i|^2-|z-i|^2)$. @PietroPaparella would it be useful for your work to take inequalities that involve $Re(z)$ and $Im(z)$, and rewrite them by subsituting in those expressions $\frac{1}{4}(|z+1|^2-|z-1|^2)$ and $\frac{1}{4}(|z+i|^2-|z-i|^2)$? Would this help get your requested "a set of inequalities involving the modulus"? (These expressions are far from unique, so other ones might be more useful, depending on what you're trying to do.)

Comment: @ZachTeitler There is one issue that remains to be clarified: whether the modulus function is regarded as a function mapping to $\mathbb{C}$ or to $\mathbb{R}$. This is not a pedantic distinction because it's not clear that OP wants to include the standard inclusion $\mathbb{R} \hookrightarrow \mathbb{C}$ as part of the underlying signature of the theory. I think my main question is whether, in the absence of allowing direct images, composition of definable functions would be admitted as definable. (Allowing only Boolean combinations of definable sets is pretty weak and constraining.)

Comment: @ZachTeitler: I was not aware of those identities, but they are quite useful for my purposes.